# Best practice to parse html (not XML) to XElement?

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I have this code:

```
var url = textBox1.Text;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

var page= wc.DownloadString(url);
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(page);
```

It fails with exception about unexpected characters.
Obviously, the HTML i'm trying to parse in such a dumb way is not strict xml.
What's the next easiest way to parse arbitrary HTML to something IQueriable?

What I actually want is to grab a table inside and paging links.
Then parse them on my own with LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the HTML Agility Pack:
http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Comment: Yeah, kinda trying with this one. Seems like it fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think of is to search for the   tags and parse everything inside, same for the tags containing the paging links. Hopefully narrowing it down to that should make a manual parser to write.